# How to remove ListView highlight color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am implementing List View in my app, but the list view highlight color does not suit my app so I need to hide it or remove it, but could not find a way to do it.

Here is an image of the app with the highlight color I want to remove. You might notice that there is a shadow effect which weirdly overlaps the highlight effect.

[image: The red circular shape]

Comment: If your app is not following material design principle, don't use `MaterialApp` to begin with. You can use `WidgetApp` which doesn't introduce things like that.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I understand their concern that the overscroll glow sometimes introduces a really harsh cut into an otherwise clean design. Material Design is a guideline and thus removing some elements does not mean that you cannot take advantage of other elements.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**EDIT :**

Prefer the solution from [How to remove scroll glow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51119795/how-to-remove-scroll-glow) instead.

While the solution shown here works, it doesn't actually *removes* the glow. It cancels it. This is less optimized as resources to create glow effects are still there. And less customizable because it doesn't allow replacing Glow with a different effect (such as fade).

---

You can insert in your widget tree a `NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>`

and then call on notification `overscrollIndicatorNotification.disallowGlow()`

```
 NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
    onNotification: (overscroll) {
      overscroll.disallowGlow();
    },
    child: new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new ListTile(
          title: new Text("data"),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

You can insert `NotificationListener` wherever you like. As long as it's a child of `MaterialApp` and above the desired `ListView`. It doesn't need to be a direct parent of that `ListView`.

Comment: Have not considered disabling it due to the title. Good solution.

Comment: @Remi Rousellet Can you please tell me your source of learning for Flutter, because I have never seen the NotificationListenerwidget in any youtube tutorial.

Comment: I don't have any. I just read flutter documentation. Flutter is really well documented.

Comment: You didn't return true on the onNotification func

Comment: @RémiRousselet It says: this function has return type bool but doesn't end with return statement. or is it ok if I put return; at the end of the function?

Comment: overscroll.disallowGlow is deprecated  => use this ->                                                                           onNotification: (overscroll) {
        overscroll.disallowIndicator();
       return true; },